# Sharing session (Redis) from Legacy PHP App with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, redis

I am trying to share a session from a Legacy PHP application with a Laravel app,

I have Redis setup and can see the session keys in Laravel using `Redis::command('keys', ['*'])`

But I'm confused how I am supposed to access the current user's session values in Laravel, for example I have a value stored as `test` but doing something like `Redis::get('test')` returns NULL.

If I look up one of the keys using `Redis::command('keys', ['*'])`

I can get the value, for example `Redis::get('PHPREDIS_SESSION:KEY')` returns the serialized test key value pair, but how can I get this value or the session key without looking up all of them?

I feel like I'm missing a basic concept or something obvious, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want both apps to use the exact same session store always, or do you want the Laravel app to have its own but also be able to pull from the legacy's session sometimes? Generally, sharing session data across multiple apps is asking for trouble, although maybe one writer and multiple readers might be okay.

Comment: Hi, yeah that is the plan we want to add new features using Laravel, but need to keep the older application running and use the data it stores in session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I worked out how to do this, make sure to add a `.` to your session domain, so it can be used across subdomains.

You can then access the session key by doing the following:

```
$session_id = session_id();
$redis_key = "PHPREDIS_SESSION:{$session_id}";
$serialized_value = Redis::get($redis_key);

// unserialize the value to access the actual data
$session_data = unserialize($serialized_value);
```

It's also worth noting, to use PHP's `unserialize` function you need to make sure `session.serialize_handler` is using `php_serialize` and not `php`.

Hope this helps someone in the future.